# Is DTiles gone forever?

Tags: tools, dungeon

Now that Undermountain Games has gone out of business, that brings an untimely death to one of the easiest dungeon-making software programs I've ever seen. It's sad to lose such a great program, and considering its potential I was wondering if anyone has heard of maybe some other company picking up DTiles and continuing with it where Undermountain failed.

Comment: While the writing style sounds somewhat as asking for opinions, the underlying question seems suitable for the site: It is not a shopping question since it asks about a specific tool. If the tool was taken over by another company this can be factually answered. Vote to leave open.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to argue "forever" but the company have cut its cord with the printing company that made the tiles for them. They still own the rights, so unless they sell those rights off, we can only hope for someone making a DTiles-like product.

My guess would be to look into some of Paizo publishings latest project. They seem stable in their economy and have several gamemaster-aid products.